# Limit the range of x in seaborn distplot KDE estimation

Tags: python, seaborn, kernel-density

Suppose we have an array with numbers between 0 and 1:

```
arr=np.array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.6934264 ,
               0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
               0.        ,  0.        ,  0.6934264 ,  0.        ,  0.6934264 ,
               0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.251463  ,
               0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.87104906,  0.251463  ,
               0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
               0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.48419626,
               0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
               0.87104906,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.251463  ,  0.48419626,
               0.        ,  0.251463  ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
               0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
               0.        ,  0.251463  ,  0.        ,  0.35524532,  0.        ,
               0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.251463  ,
               0.251463  ,  0.        ,  0.74209813,  0.        ,  0.        ])
```

Using `seaborn`, I want to plot a distribution plot:

```
sns.distplot(arr, hist=False)
```

Which will give us the following figure:
[image]

As you can see, the kde estimation ranges from somewhere near -0.20 to 1.10. Is it possible to force the estimation to be between 0 and 1? I have tried the followings with no luck:

```
sns.distplot(arr, hist=False, hist_kws={'range': (0.0, 1.0)})
sns.distplot(arr, hist=False, kde_kws={'range': (0.0, 1.0)})
```

The second line raises an exception -- `range` not a valid keyword for `kde_kws`.

Comment: I am confused because with seaborn 0.8.1 `sns.distplot(arr, hist=False)` gives me a different plot: zero is excluded by the curve as if it is not part of `arr`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The correct way of doing this, is by using the `clip` keyword instead of `range`:

```
sns.distplot(arr, hist=False, kde_kws={'clip': (0.0, 1.0)})
```

which will produce:
[image]

Indeed, if you only care about the kde and not the histogram, you can use the `kdeplot` function, which will produce the same result:

```
sns.kdeplot(arr, clip=(0.0, 1.0))
```

Comment: Does this actually recalculate the kde or just cuts off the part outside the range?

Comment: Is there a way to do this on the KernelDensity.fit() function as well?

Comment: It does recalculate the kde @Peaceful

Comment: @R.Cox : I think it doesn't. I tried plotting kde with and without clipping and they just overlap.

Comment: You're right it doesn't re-calculate the kde; your 2 curves overlap. I was using it for a different application and in that case it was changing. I've just tried the code from the question and it gave me a completely different graph. On my computer it is now using smaller bins!

Comment: Where should I post my graph please?

Answer (score 9):

Setting `plt.xlim(0, 1)` beforehand should help :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.xlim(0, 1)
sns.distplot(arr, hist=False)
```

Comment: Doesn't work with FacetGrid

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind bars on the plot, besides KDE, `sns.histplot()` does the clipping automatically, according to data range:

`sns.histplot(arr, kde=True, stat='density')`
[image: histplot with KDE]