# continues density plot seaborn with lower limit

Tags: plot, parameters, seaborn, probability, probability-density

I have been using this code for my continues parameters to plot the probability distributions. However, my parameter now is price that cant be below zero, I have been reading to see if I can customize the density function so it dsnt go into negative numbers but havnt really found an answer. Does anyone know if there is a way to bound the density function?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
sns.distplot(data2018[ 'price'], hist=False)
sns.distplot(data2020[ 'price'], hist=False)
fig.legend(labels=['2018','2020'], bbox_to_anchor=(0.9,0.85))
```

Comment: See [Limit the range of x in seaborn distplot KDE estimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911709/limit-the-range-of-x-in-seaborn-distplot-kde-estimation)

Comment: Basically, there are negative values because that how a KDE works. [“Negative density” for non-negative variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109549/negative-density-for-non-negative-variables)